# how to insert .txt into python to define a keyword list

Tags: python

I would like to insert a .txt file such as notepad to define a keyword list. For example my current code is something like this :

```
key_word_list = ['pig,dog,cat']
```

My real list is much bigger and it would be a lot more organised to have it in a .txt file

i would like to know if its possible to have a .txt to define the keywords in the list.

Thankyou

Comment: Do you want to save the whole list or only the string? @Callum

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of such an input file? Oh and btw notepad is not a text file, it is an editor.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You would use something like this:

```
with open('fileName.txt', 'r') as f:
    yourList = [yourList.strip() for yourList in f]
```

Then you could print using
    print(yourList)

Comment: you mean `yourList.split()`?

Comment: Can you explain to me why you used `yourList` as the variable name for both, the actual list as well as every line in your file? Does it come with an efficiency boost? If not, it will only confuse beginners....@Greg That would return a list containing lists that each hold words in a line. Would not make much sense, would it? Tbh OPs question is unclear anyways.

Comment: @Krazor - The naming convention is just personal preference. For me, I like to have a minimum number of variable names, so in this case, instead of having two variables (one for the final list and then one for the list in the function) I just used one. I could have very well used `yourList = [yourList.strip() for yourList in f]` and it would accomplish the same task.  From what I understand about the question is that the OP has a file that he wants to be outside of his program to hold these words. The file can always be updated without having to make and code modifications.

Comment: I know, but tbh that is a really bad coding habit. Oh and btw the code in your comment and the code in your answer are exactly the same.